# How do you extend templates in Leaf using the #extend and #export tags in leaf?

Tags: swift, vapor, server-side-swift, leaf

The Leaf documentation doesn't seem to be working for me I can't figure out why.

`child.leaf`

```
#extend("index"):
    #export("hello"):
        <p>Welcome to Vapor!</p>
    #endexport
#endextend
```

`index.leaf`

```
<!-- Backend Projects -->
<div class="seciton-label">
    <h3>#(.backendCollection.title)</h3>
</div>
  
#import("hello")
 
<!-- Backend Card -->
#for(card in .backendCollection.collection):
<div class="greeting-card">
    <a href=#(card.url)>
        <h3>#(card.title)</h3>
    </a>
    <p> #(card.description) </p>
</div>
#endfor
```

The following image is the result I get in localhost

[Request result running the vapor server on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv2Rj.png)

Please help - I can't find solutions to this issue.
No response from forums.swift.org

- Tried removing the import key
- Removing quotes
- I saw individuals using the following format in older versions of Vapor. This did not work for me either.

```
<!-- I tried the following format for the extend and export blocks -->

#extend("index") {
    #export("hello") {
        <p>Welcome to Vapor!</p>
    }
}
```

I'm trying to be able to extend the leaf templates and understand why the html does not render.

Answer (score 1):

This works and does something similar to what you want.

This is my 'template' (heavily simplified here), called `Base.leaf`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>#(title)</title>
   </head>
   <body>
        #import("body")
   </body>
</html>
#extend("Build/Message")
</body>
</html>
```

The extend of `Build/Message` above behaves simply like an include.

Then I use it in a form called `Login.leaf` here:

```html
#extend("Build/Base"):
#export("body"):
<form method="POST" action="/log-in">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" required>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" required>
    <button class="btn-success">Log-in</button>
</form>
#endexport
#endextend
```

I then use the `Login.leaf' in a render such as:

```swift
let context = ["title": "Log in", "version": C.Msg.Version, "message": request.getMessage()]
return try await request.view.render("Form/Login", context)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and pardon my ignorance, but I'm seeing some things I haven't seen before. You mentioned Build/Message behaves like include, I was not able to find an explanation of what this is the Vapor documentation. Would you mind explaining?  Also, if export is called to store the html and make it available to the template we're currently extending. Why do you extend "Build/Message" in Base.leaf instead of "Base" or even "Build/Base" if "Build/" has a function I'm unaware of?

Comment: I use the folder Build to store small Leaf files that are used on some or all of the pages. In this case, Message simply checks for a value in the tag `Message` and puts it in an alert when the page is first loaded. I use it to pass information and error messages to the user.

Comment: I also use Leaf to render content that is passed to weasyprint to generate PDF files.

Comment: Thank you much Nick. Great info.